# Is it possible to update existing Google cloud dataflow pipelines when using template for deployment ?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When deploying google dataflow pipeline as templates, Is it possible to update the pipeline using another version of the template?

Basically, I am looking for a combination https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline with https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview

Comment: You should just have to rerun the template creation and staging command. If that did not work please explain what exactly you did and what happened (editing your question is probably best).

Answer (score 3):

The feature of updating an existing job from template API is not ready yet. (We are working on it).

At the time, you can probably make use our public repo (basically the source code for these templates) to do it. Basically, you can just build and launch the job to "update" the running job from a shell.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates

Comment: Zhou Yunqing, could you please tell what progress on implementing this feature? I have the same feature request.

Comment: I also have the same request

Answer (score 2):

Now it's possible to update a template streaming Dataflow job.

Using the REST API, set the `update` parameter to true:

```
POST https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/templates/TemplateName
{
    "jobName": "JOB_NAME",
    "parameters": {
        "topic": "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/topics/YOUR_TOPIC_NAME",
        "table": "YOUR_PROJECT_ID:YOUR_DATASET.YOUR_TABLE_NAME"
    },
    "environment": {
        "tempLocation": "gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/temp",
        "zone": "us-central1-f"
    }
    "update": true
}
```

The update option is not present using [gcloud dataflow jobs run](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run).

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#example-3:-updating-a-custom-template-streaming-job
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/LaunchTemplateParameters